# how to get possible sequences of array items in javascript without recursive function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to generate all permutation of array items order with javascript and without recursive. 
I mean if array length is equal to n then n! possible sequences.
There are some solutions with recursive but I am looking for without recursive.
Maybe I can explain it better with the following example:

```
let arr = ['A','B','C'];

console.log(generateOrders(arr));

//and waiting followings: 
A, B, C
A, C, B
B, A, C
B, C, A
C, A, B
C, B, A
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Why do you not want recursive option ?

Comment: Most (but not all!) recursive tasks can be done with loops. This one can. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Here's a worked example without using recursion: https://medium.com/@lindagmorales94/how-to-solve-a-string-permutation-problem-using-javascript-95ad5c388219

Comment: @rootkonda I am solving a problem and I want to compare for complexity and performance but I cant create an efficient approach for loops.

Comment: Thank you so much @paul

Comment: ok. Especially for this kind of permutation problems, loops are inefficient. Recursion is the way to go.

Comment: @rootkonda recursion is a type of loop.

Comment: Well, conceptually you can say its a form of iteration. But the way of working is totally different. Hope you are aware of that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the functions I created when solving Project Euler problems, which gets the lexicographical permutations of an array:

```js
Array.prototype.getPermutations = function() {
  const a = this.valueOf().sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
  const l = a.length - 1
  const findX = () => {
    for (let i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (a[i] < a[i + 1]) {
        return i
      }
    }
    return null
  }

  const findY = x => {
    for (let i = l; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (a[i] > a[x]) {
        return i
      }
    }
    return null
  }

  const swap = (arr, a, b) => {
    const t = arr[a]
    arr[a] = arr[b]
    arr[b] = t
    return arr
  }

  const p = [a.slice()]
  while (true) {
    let x = findX()
    if (x === null) return p
    let y = findY(x)
    swap(a, x, y)
    if (l - x > 1) {
      a.splice(x + 1, l - x + 2, ...a.slice(x + 1).reverse())
    }
    p.push(a.slice())
  }
}

const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C']
console.log(arr.getPermutations())
```

It is based upon the algorithm described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order):

> The following algorithm generates the next permutation lexicographically after a given permutation. It changes the given permutation in-place.
>
> 1. Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1]. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
> 2. Find the largest index l greater than k such that a[k] < a[l].
> 3. Swap the value of a[k] with that of a[l].
> 4. Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].

There are definitely better algorithms, but I noticed this output matched yours.

Comment: Isn’t the `valueOf()` a no-op?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non recursive solution:

```js
function options(arr){
  var res = [];
  arr = [{pre:'', item: arr}];
  var t;
  while(t = arr.shift()) {
    if(t.item.length === 1){
      res.push(t.pre+t.item);
    }else {
      for(var j=0;j<t.item.length;j++){
      arr.push({pre: t.pre+t.item[j], item: [...t.item.slice(0, j),...t.item.slice(j+1)]});
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(options([1,2,3,4]));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could look on  [js-combinatorics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-combinatorics). There might be your solution:

```
cmb = Combinatorics.permutation(['A','B','C']); // assumes 3
while(a = cmb.next()) console.log(a.join());

// in console output
A,B,C
A,C,B
B,A,C
B,C,A
C,A,B
C,B,A
```

Comment: Yeah, but the library itself probably use recursive solution.. honestly I really think recursive here is the best thing to do, but..